# Parsing data with perl- capturing a range of text

Tags: regex, perl

I'm writing code to parse all the interfaces on my network, looking for certain configurations.. etc.

the data looks like this:

```
Interface fa1
  mode access
  port-security
  mac-address sticky
!
interface fa2
  mode trunk
!
```

Basically starting with "^interface " and ending "!".

my current algorithm is to "record" the data I need

```
foreach $line (@input) {
    if ( $line =~ m/^interface.+\d/ && $line !~ m/interface Embedded-Service-Engine|BRI|TenGigabitEthernet|vlan|Port-channel|ATM|loopback/i) {
        $record = 1;
    }

    #$int ne '' is to handle the rest of the file not in this format
    if( $line =~ m/!/ && $int ne '') {

        #save data in format 'interface fa2,mode trunk'
        #if the interface doesn't have port-security
        push(@intlist, join(','split("\r\n",$int))."\n") unless $int =~ m/port-security/;
        $record=0;
        $int='';
    }
    if ($record) {
         $int.=$line;
    }
 }
```

while this works in my case, I'd like a simply way to do it. I've searched and found that you can use the range operator '..' on regex

which turns my code into :

```
@input # contains the file
@interfaces = grep (/^interface.+\d/ .. /!/, @input);
```

which gives me all the interface data, the problem is now every line is a single element in the `@interfaces` array. how can I then split this data up so everything from `/^interface.+\d/ .. /!/` is one element in this array without creating more for loops?

The goal is to get it down to one element so I can then scan it for interfaces I don't want to look at `interface Embedded-Service-Engine|BRI|TenGigabit` as well as interfaces that have the correct configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my Final solution. In this particular case I'm searching for all switchports that have a maximum port-security not equal to 1. This is just an example and can be switched for any configuration. I'm also omitting certain interfaces from being caught if that configuration is actually applied to them.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$MDIR='/currentConfig';

#list of interfaces you don't want to see to filter output
@omit =(
'MANAGEMENT.PORT',
'sup.mgmt',
'Internal.EtherSwitch',
'Router',
'ip address \d',
'STRA'
);
#join with '|' to form the regex
$dontwant = join('|',@omit);

#search criteria
$search='switchport port-security maximum [^1]';

opendir(DIR,$MDIR) or die $!;
@dirContents=readdir DIR;close DIR;

foreach $file (@dirContents) {
        open(IN,$MDIR.'/'.$file) or die $!;
        #record seperator to !
        $/='!';
        my @inFile=<IN>; close IN;
        #since the record seperator has been changed, '^' won't match beginning of line
        my @ints = grep (/\ninterface/i,@inFile);
        #set record seperator back to normal
        $/="\n";
        foreach $int (@ints) {
                if ( $int =~ m/$search/i && $int !~ m/$dontwant/) {
                        push(@finalint,$int);
                }
        }
}
#just list the interfaces found, i'll use this to make it comma seperated
foreach $elem (@finalint) {
        print $elem;
}
```

Comment: Ok. I see what you're getting at. To answer your question "Why bother to use a complicating hash?": it depends. Since you're just putting strings into @int, your data seems a bit unstructured. If you're only goal is knowing what interfaces are having substrings $seach and not $dontwant in them, I would say no. If you actuallly need to DO something with the interfaces and their underlying fields, then yes, it will be beneficial to use a hash for some structure. I think a fair question to ask what would be, what you need to do with your data. One more thing: use local for your separator. ;)

Comment: @mlambrichs Thanks, I tried to 'my' the separator, but wasn't compiling. local works just fine.

Comment: Also: `strict` and `warnings` come strongly recommended.

Comment: @Sobrique yeah I've never actually coded perl with that... I know I'm bad haha I'm just a get the job done guy but i'll start looking into it and what it can do for me.

Comment: It makes life harder initially, but makes some really annoying bugs go away.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `$/` because I think that'll help. It's the record separator - which defaults to `\n`.

Then you can apply regular expressions to the current 'chunk' to pull out the data you require - by default a regular expression/capture group applies to `$_` the implicit variable.

E.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


local $/ = '!';

while ( <DATA> ) {
    my ( $interface ) = m/Interface (\w+)/i;
    next if $interface =~ m/Embedded-Service-Engine/;
    my ( $mode ) = m/mode (\w+)/;

    print "$interface $mode\n";

    print "---next record---\n";
}

__DATA__
Interface fa1
  mode access
  port-security
  mac-address sticky
!
interface fa2
  mode trunk
!
```

If you need to keep the data for other uses (e.g. 'process as you go' isn't suitable) then the tool for the job is a hash.

You can either use something like the above - and populate the hash with particular keys you're interested in - or use the magic of map to do it for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
local $/ = '!';

my %interfaces; 

while ( <DATA> ) {
    my ( $interface ) = m/Interface (\w+)/i; 
    next if $interface =~ m/Embedded-Service-Engine/;
    my %interface_values =  map { my ( $key, $value ) = split; $key, $value || 1 } grep { /\w/ } split ( "\n" );
    $interfaces{$interface} = \%interface_values;
}

print Dumper \%interfaces

__DATA__
Interface fa1
  mode access
  port-security
  mac-address sticky
!
interface fa2
  mode trunk
!
```

That `map` line basically:

- splits the current record on `\n` to get each line.
- filters 'not word' values (so blank lines and !)
- splits each line on whitepace, to get a key and value pair.
- If no value is defined, sets it to 1. (so in the example, `port-security` )
- Populates a hash with these key-value pairs.
- and then updates `%interfaces` with the hash for each interface ID.

Giving something like:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'fa1' => {
                     'port-security' => 1,
                     'mode' => 'access',
                     'Interface' => 'fa1',
                     'mac-address' => 'sticky'
                   },
          'fa2' => {
                     'mode' => 'trunk',
                     'interface' => 'fa2'
                   }
        };
```

Comment: thanks, the $/ variable is probably what I'm looking for. I haven't had a chance to try it yet.

my script is more complicated than what I posted, I was trying to make it readable so everyone could understand what I'm trying to achieve.

in the end I need to look at all the interfaces on my network and extract all of the ones I choose ( ones that don't have a certain configuration, trunk links, etc) just depends on what report I'm trying to run. 

A quick question, what it be "worth" it to make the structure more complicated than an array? I just want to run a regex the entire interface config

Comment: Depends what you are doing with the structure.  Hashes are pretty handy when you have keys and values like you do. But it depends really.

Comment: I got it. Thanks. I just create reports based off this interface data so I can use my other scripts to go out there and apply configs to interfaces that missing some of the default configs.

Answer (score 1):

A hash or hashref would be a result where you can work with. Furthermore, reading records based on a fixed structure can be read using a matching regex. Like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

our %MATCH;
*MATCH = \%+;

# read file into variable
my ( $file, $data ) = ( 'interfaces.txt', undef );
open( my $fh, '<', $file ) or die "cannot open file $file";
{
    local $/;
    $data = <$fh>;
}
close($fh);
print Dumper $data;

my $regex = qr{
  (?sm)
  interface           [^\w\n]+
  (?<interface>       (\w[^\n]+))
                      [^\w]+
  mode                [^\w]+
  (?<mode>            (\w[^\n]+))
                      [^\w]+
  ((?<portsecurity>   port-security)
                      [^\w]+)?        # port-security is optional
  (mac-address        [^\w]+
  (?<macaddress>      (\w[^\n]+))
                      )?              # mac-address is optional
  [^!]*
  !
}x;

my $results = {};
while ( $data =~ m/$regex/g ) {
    my $interface = $MATCH{interface};
    $results->{$interface} = { mode => $MATCH{mode} ? $MATCH{mode} : '' };
    $results->{$interface}->{'port-security'} = 1
      if defined $MATCH{portsecurity};
    $results->{$interface}->{macaddress} = $MATCH{macaddress}
      if defined $MATCH{macaddress};
}
print Dumper $results;
```

The result from your input is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'fa1' => {
                     'macaddress' => 'sticky',
                     'mode' => 'access',
                     'port-security' => 1
                   },
          'fa2' => {
                     'mode' => 'trunk'
                   }
        };
```

Having a hash with the interface names as key values, gives you the opportunity to use a 'grep' for the interfaces you want.

If your structure is not fixed - there is no ordering in your fields mode, port-security, mac-address - then you would need to read a interface record in one go, and split up the fields using separate regexes for each field.

Comment: The thing is, there can be any amount of configurations on the interfaces. Just depends on its function. - I will look into the $/ operator. thanks!

Comment: The '$/' operator was my solution. Can you look at my posted answer and see how a hash would make it better? seems to me it would just overly complicate it.

Comment: Both presented solutions use the record separator. The difference is do you need to read the data in one go ($/ = '') or separate the data in records while reading ($/ = '!'). I've put my follow-up as a comment to your suggested solution. We need more input, I guess.